# Simple Recursion Explanation

Tags: java, recursion

Here is a recursive static method in Java.

```
public static int mystery(int m, int n) {
    int result = 1;   

    if (m > 0) {
      result = n * mystery(m-1, n);
    }       

    System.out.println (m + "  " + result);
    return result;
}
```

What will be printed to the standard output if we make the method call mystery(3,4)? What would be the final return value from the call to mystery(3,4)?

What is the explanation to the answer for the standard output part.

Output:

```
0 1
1 4
2 16
3 64
```

The final return value is 64.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: No, I am trying to understand recursion through this example

Comment: Tagged as homework, but not homework. Sneaky stuff man.

Answer (score 5):

Consider `n` to be fixed (which for all intents and purposes it is) and let `f(m)` be `mystery(m,n)`.

Then

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = n * f(0) = n
f(2) = n * f(1) = n * n
f(3) = n * f(2) = n * n * n
```

Can you see the general pattern? Can you give a closed form for `f(n)`?

Answer (score 2):

Given your code which is

```
public static int mystery(int m, int n) {
int result = 1;   

if (m > 0) {
  result = n * mystery(m-1, n);
}       

System.out.println (m + "  " + result);
return result;
}
```

Lets start with m = 3 and n = 4, lets try to emulate it by trying to be the debugger...

```
mystery(3,4){
   int result = 1
   if(3 > 0){
       result = 4 * mystery(3-1,4);
       //We proceed from this point only after evaluating mystery(2,4)
       mystery(2,4){
            int result = 1
            if(2 > 0){
                result = 4*mystery(2-1,4);
                //Now we have to evaluate mystery(1,4)
                mystery(1,4){
                    int result = 1;
                      if(1 > 0){
                          result = 4*mystery(1-1,4);
                          //Evaluate mystery(0,4)
                          mystery(0,4){
                             int result = 1;
                             if(0 > 0){
                                //Not evaluated
                             }
                             System.out.println(0 + " "+1);
                             return 1;
                          }...mystery(0,4) done continue with evaluation of mystery(1,4)
                          result = 4*1 //1 is what is returned by mystery(0,4)
                          System.out.println(1+ "" + 4);
                          return 4; 
                       }//done with the evaluation of mystery(1,4), resume evaluation of mystery(2,4)
                result = 4*4 //4 is the value returned by mystery(1,4)
                System.out.println(2 + " " + 16);
                return 16;            
                }//At this point we are done with evaluating (2,4) and on the way to resume evaluation of mystery(3,4)
       result = 4 * 16
       System.out.println(3 + " "+ 64)
       return 64;
       }
   }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This sample calculates m to the power n.
So in your case the value is 64.

However have you tried it out and did analysis on your part?

Answer (score 0):

The first call is mystery(3,4) which then calls mystery(2,4) which then calls mystery(1,4) which then calls mystery(0,4).  In this example, the base case is mystery(0,4), i.e. m > 0 evaluates to false and result = n*mystery(m-1,n) will not get executed (recursion terminates here).  Your base case is on top of the call stack and the bottom of your stack is mystery(3,4).  Evaluate from the top of the call stack towards the bottom…

[image]